# Continue the time in java-script after click on back button in browser or in keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

Actually I am developed one online exam portal in that exam portal i am set the time 10 min like code (In java-script):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var sec = 01;   // set the seconds
        var min = 10;   // set the minutes
        var canno = 0;
        function countDown() {
            sec--;
            if (sec == -01) {
                sec = 59;
                min = min - 1;
            }
            else {
                min = min;
            }
            if (sec <= 9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
            time = (min <= 9 ? "0" + min : min) + " mins : " + sec + " sec ";
            if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('theTime').innerHTML = time; }
            SD = window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
            if (min == '00' && sec == '00') {
                alert("TimesUp! Moving to Next Page");

                var answer = document.getElementById('<%=txtEssay.ClientID%>').value;
                window.open("English_Skills.aspx?CandNo=<%=CandidateNumber%>&QuesNo=<%=QuesNo%>&a1=" + answer, "_self", "");

                sec = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
            }
        }
        window.onload = countDown;
    </script>
```

and also if the click on back button in browser or keyboard it will not going to preview page  like code in java-script:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" >
        function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
        window.onunload = function () { null };
  </script>
```

**The problem**

if the time is running on 5:30 min out of 10:00 min if the click on back button on browser or in keyboard the time reset and it will coming on 10:00 min.I don't want come on 10:00 min i want to continue the time 5:30 to 10:00 how it is ...

Please help me

Thanks

pradeep

Comment: Have u tried to store it on a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always rely on server side code for timing things of this nature. The client/browser is easy to fool or fake. Not only is doing this sort of thing difficult, but it is generally much less secure than doing it server side.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is use Web workers to run the javascript in back ground and set the time in something like cookie
check this link for web workers

http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

and note one thing web workers are available only for mordern browsers they wont work for old browsers

or you can handle this with cookies